# Calculating lagrange error term

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have the function $ \ln \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} $
I found its maclaurin series by using the known series for $\ln (1+x)$ and then approximated $\ln 2$ using the first three terms of this series.

How do I find the lagrange error term now? Do I have to go through the derivatives of $ \ln \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} $ or is there an easier way?

Comment: To estimate the error specifically after the third term, you only need one more derivative.

Comment: but I didn't calculate the derivatives to form its maclaurin series. I instead used the known maclaurin series of $ ln(1+x)$

Comment: Are you requesting to have a general form for the Lagrange remainder?  Or are you only looking for the remainder for the 3 term approximation?  Or are you seeking any "useful" estimate of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)$.  We can develop the series expansion of $f(x)$ by using the series expansions for $\log(1+x)$ and $\log(1-x)$.

These are respectively

$$\begin{align}
\log(1+x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}\\\\\log(1-x)&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
\end{align}$$

for $|x|<1$, whereby we see that

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right)\\\\&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{((-1)^{n-1}+1)x^n}{n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Using the series in $(1)$, we see that $\log(2)=\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+3/5}{1-3/5}}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3/5)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.

The Lagrange form of the remainder of the series is given by

$$R_n=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

The $n$th derivative of $f(x)$ is trivial using $f(x)=\frac12\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right)$.  Then, we have

$$f^{(n+1)}(\xi)=\frac{n!}{2}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(1+\xi)^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{(1-\xi)^{n+1}}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I ended up doing specifically for the 6th derivative as I had only used terms up to $x^5$

Comment: Now, to (over) estimate the $n+1$th derivative, take absolute value of $(-1)^{n}$, and use $\xi=0$ in the first term and $\xi =3/5$ in the second.  It is crude, but does provide a useful error estimate.  We could also use an integral remainder to estimate the error.

Comment: And you're quite welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark